# Mysql join tables with PHP - without any luck

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables: `campaigns` and `accounts`

In `accounts` I have `accountid` column and `accountName` column.

In `campaigns` I have `ExternalCustomerId` and `AccountDescriptiveName`.
`ExternalCustomerId` holds `accountid`

So what I am trying to do is to get list of all campaigns and join the account Name to table where External Customer Id = account id

[image]

But all what I have tried without any luck

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you tried. This looks like it should be a simple `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I agree with Barmar.  This may help: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  However, is the problem with the SQL or the php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:-

`SELECT ExternalCustomerId,AccountDescriptiveName,accountName
FROM accounts
LEFT OUTER JOIN campaigns
ON accounts.accountid=campaigns.ExternalCustomerId;`

For more knowledge follow MySQL documents http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), here is an example:

```
SELECT c.ExternalCustomerId , c.AccountDescriptiveName, a.accountName 
FROM campaigns c
LEFT JOIN accounts a
ON c.ExternalCustomerId = a.accountid
WHERE c.ExternalCustomerId = ?
```

Check the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to learn more about the syntax